# How to get notification for CREATE/DROP/ALTER table events in Hive using NotificationListener

Tags: hive, event-listener, hive-metastore

I am new using Hive. Can someone please assist how to get notification using `DbNotificationListener` in Hive whenever any database event related to CREATE/DROP/ALTER happens.

I have below question related to steps:

1. Which JAR file I need to use for `NotificationListener` class? Can it be Hcatalog JAR for Hive meta store?
2. What is the class path where I should add this JAR file?
3. Which entry I need to make in `hive-Site.xml`?
4. Will it write events in meta store log?

Thanks in advance.